# php I want to open a php file with my IDE from a site, how?

Tags: php, ide, hyperlink

its strange first, but it would help my work faster. What kind of link should I make on a local .php file so that my IDE would open it? Php files are associated with it already

Comment: FTP/SFTP/SSH would be a start. What IDE are you working with ?

Comment: What is your IDE? What do you mean by link? (A symlink or what?) And what does loading "from a site" mean technically?

Comment: Opening a PHP file remotely via HTTP is not generally possible, since it's very rare for .php files to be served up as raw code - you'd actually be executing the script and simply loading its output. You'll need some OTHER method of fetching the file, like ftp/sftp/scp as kevingreen's mentioned.

Comment: not remotely, I meant my localhost only. For example, if you open a .bmp file, your pain/photoshop starts with it, if on .mp3, your player will start with it, on .php file your IDE would open it

Comment: You must associate the `.php` file extension with your IDE

Comment: I guess you're after something like TextMate's txmt:// URL scheme? http://blog.macromates.com/2007/the-textmate-url-scheme/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution if your on windows, it will display all files within a directory, when you click the link it will open the file on the server so be careful:

```
<?php
//path to project dir, basic loop out directory contents.
$dir = "C:/xampp/htdocs/";
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            echo '<a href="?start='.$file.'">'.$file."</a><br>\n";
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
}

//file link clicked
if(isset($_GET['start'])){
    start_ide(basename($_GET['start']));
}

//use shell_exe to open the file
function start_ide($file){
    global $dir;
    shell_exec('@START '.$dir.'/'.$file);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are asking is how to associate PHP files with your IDE?
If that is the case, and your on a windows based PC, then

1. right-click on a .php file, click properties,
2. under the "General" tab, click the "Change" button to the right of the "Open With:".
3. select your IDE
4. click OK/apply

That should do it.

Comment: no, not really. Its done, but I want to put a link on it. If I put "<a href="E:\link\to\file.php">link</a>" browser says it cant understand

Comment: Ahh, install eg. WAMP (http://www.wampserver.com/en/) and put your .php files into the "wamp/www/" folder :)

Comment: but it then interpreters that script, I want it to be opened in my IDE

Comment: If I understand you correctly then what you are saying is, that when you try to make a link to another php file on your local drive, it won't intrepid the file? Or try to give me as many details you can of what you are after.

Comment: Ah, well you need to make sure that ALL .php files are within the folder of eg "c:/wamp/www" else the local server won't intrepid the files.